# Multiple Queries with Conditional Statements in MQL

Tags: freebase, mql

Is there a way to write queries for questions like

> list of movies which are produced and directed by the same person?

In SPARQL/SQL this is easy, but in MQL is it possible to write this in a single query.

In general, can MQL be used for queries which require trace variables and conditional statements?

**Update:** A lengthier discussion on this topic at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/freebase-discuss/EfB04zznvco

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible in MQL. Often those sorts of queries take longer to execute and would time-out in our web API.

Here's about as close as you can get in MQL:

```
[{
  "id": null,
  "type1:type": "/film/director",
  "type2:type": "/film/producer",
  "name": null,
  "/film/director/film": [{}],
  "/film/producer/film": [{}]
}]
```

Then you just need to find the intersection of the films that they've directed and the films they've produced.

Usually, anything that resembles a recommendation system is better off being run offline using the [Freebase data dumps](https://developers.google.com/freebase/data).